# An inequality concerning the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an SPD matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let $Ax_i=\lambda_ix_i, \ (i=1,\cdots,n)$ be an eigensystem of the symmetric positive-definite diagonally-dominant matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}$. Let

$$b_{jk}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{(x_i(j)-x_i(k))^2}{\lambda_i}} \ ,$$

where $x_i(j)$ denotes the $j$-th component of the eigenvector $x_i$.

> Is it true that $1+a_{jk} b_{jk}>0$? If not, under what condition is it true?

Comment: sorry, $x_j({q})$ should be $x_i({q})$, i've made a mistake

Comment: Is A=[2 0 0;0 5 -1;0 -1 2], q=2, p=3 a counterexample?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik The matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 5 & -1  \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{array}\right)$

Comment: @Bullet51 if i'm right, $1+a_{23}b_{23}=4/9>0$ in your case.  $\lambda_i=\{\frac{1}{2}(7+\sqrt{13}),\ 2,\ \frac{1}{2}(7-\sqrt{13}) \} $and the corresponding eigenvectors are$ (0,-0.9571,0.2898)^T, (1,0,0)^T and (0,-0.2898,-0.9571)^T$. It can be verified easily when A is a 2-by-2 SPD diagonally dominant matrix. Say if $$A=\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{12} & a_{22}\end{matrix}$$, we can verify that$$ 1+a_{12}b_{12}=\frac{(a_{11}+a_{12})(a_{22}+a_{12})}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2}$$, which satisfy the inequality. However, it is quite difficult for me to verify that in a higher dimensional case.